# java.lang.NullPointerException in project root running sbt

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm starting in Scala and I'm trying to run sbt in my project folder where `build.sbt` is. This folder is the only one when I get this error. If I run it in the `src` folder or in my Documents folder I don't get the error. Could anyone tell me why is this happening? I wouldn't know how to represent the folder structure, it would be the main root with the `build.sbt` and inside the `src` folder would be `example/src/main/scala/example/Lists.scala`. It is a folder from coursera so I didn't create it. The build is :

```
name := course.value + "-" + assignment.value

scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

scalacOptions ++= Seq("-deprecation")

// grading libraries
libraryDependencies += "junit" % "junit" % "4.10" % Test

// for funsets
libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang.modules" %% "scala-parser-combinators" % "1.0.4"

// include the common dir
commonSourcePackages += "common"

courseId := "bRPXgjY9EeW6RApRXdjJPw"
```

The error is:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.base/java.util.regex.Matcher.getTextLength(Matcher.java:1769)
    at java.base/java.util.regex.Matcher.reset(Matcher.java:416)
    at java.base/java.util.regex.Matcher.<init>(Matcher.java:253)
    at java.base/java.util.regex.Pattern.matcher(Pattern.java:1147)
    at java.base/java.util.regex.Pattern.split(Pattern.java:1264)
    at java.base/java.util.regex.Pattern.split(Pattern.java:1335)
    at sbt.IO$.pathSplit(IO.scala:744)
    at sbt.IO$.parseClasspath(IO.scala:859)
    at sbt.compiler.CompilerArguments.extClasspath(CompilerArguments.scala:62)
    at sbt.compiler.MixedAnalyzingCompiler$.withBootclasspath(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:189)
    at sbt.compiler.MixedAnalyzingCompiler$.searchClasspathAndLookup(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:167)
    at sbt.compiler.MixedAnalyzingCompiler$.apply(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:177)
    at sbt.compiler.IC$.incrementalCompile(IncrementalCompiler.scala:138)
    at sbt.Compiler$.compile(Compiler.scala:128)
    at sbt.Compiler$.compile(Compiler.scala:114)
    at sbt.Defaults$.sbt$Defaults$$compileIncrementalTaskImpl(Defaults.scala:829)
    at sbt.Defaults$$anonfun$compileIncrementalTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:820)
    at sbt.Defaults$$anonfun$compileIncrementalTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:818)
    at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
    at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:40)
    at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:63)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
    at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:17)
    at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:235)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
    at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:159)
    at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:28)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:514)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) java.lang.NullPointerException
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore? q
```

Comment: Could you provide both the folder structure of your project and the build.sbt?

Comment: Added, I hope I edited the way you needed to help me :)

Comment: Your are running SBT with Java9, which coule leader to issue the `sbt.scala.version` is not set the a version compatible with such JVM.

Comment: It worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Your issue may be an old SBT version.

Ensure you are using SBT 0.13.17+ for JDK 9 compatibility (i.e. by setting `sbt.version=0.13.17` in your project/build.properties)

reference: https://github.com/sbt/sbt/pull/3848